# How can I set two passwords for one account?

Tags: login, password, users

It would be great if I have two passwords to my account, so that if I forget one, I can still login without much trouble.

Is it possible to do this?

By "two passwords" I mean two login passwords...

Comment: I am not sure there is any way to set 2 passwords for one account. You can either create 2 accounts with sudo access or reset your password - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153276/multiple-passwords-per-user and http://askubuntu.com/questions/222092/multiple-passwords-on-one-account